# How to set Application Name property of a TADOConnection in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, adoconnection

I have a Delphi app that connects to a MS SQL server using TADOConnection.
Now I need to set "Application Name" property of a TADOConnection (so that it could be seen on DB with `select distinct program_name from sys.sysprocesses` query).

TADOConnection does not have a `ApplicationName` property. Instead it just internally assigns application executable name to it (which can be seen with a query above).

How do I set "Application Name" property of a `TADOConnection` connection with MS SQL database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Application Name" property (and others) can be set like so:

```
AdoConnection1.Properties['Application Name'].Value := 'MyAppName';
```